# make change on line and character x of txt file with cmd ( script)

Tags: windows, cmd, text-files

As I am not an expert in  script command and I am getting stuck on this script, I am asking the community for some help.

As for my problem I tried the following (see code below ) in order to change a character in a textfile on a specific location. By using `For /F` I was hoping to readout the entire file to a backup copy, and just change the wanted location to the new value by using an `IF`. However I noticed that when I put the token parameter to `tokens=6` it wouldn't copy the entire file to the new location. so I changed this to `tokens=*`. However with this the entire row on the 74th line is changed. :s and with this I also found out that ENTERS and specific characters as "!" are not copied to the backup file.

Now i was hoping that you could help me change this character on location line 74 , token 6 without further resulting in any change of the specific text file.

thanks for any advise.

```
@echo off
CLS
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set ORIGINALFILE=test.file.txt
set MODIFIEDFILE=temp1.txt
set MODIFIEDFILE2=temp_backup.txt
set SEARCHVALUE=0
set REPLACEVALUE=1
set OUTPUTLINE=
set linenumber=0
::for demo purpose make cop of original file as original will be overwritten
copy %ORIGINALFILE% %MODIFIEDFILE2%
del temp1.txt
echo "all set"
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

::everything is set now change the 6th item on the line 74 to a "1"

FOR /f "tokens=* delims=," %%G in ('"type %ORIGINALFILE%"') do (
set /a linenumber=!linenumber!+1
SET string=%%G
if !linenumber!  EQU 61 (

    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHVALUE%=%REPLACEVALUE%!
    echo !linenumber!
) else (
    echo !linenumber!
    SET modified=!string!       
)
echo !modified! >> %MODIFIEDFILE%   
)
```

Comment: You should use PowerShell rather than `cmd.exe`.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that is `bash`. I'm removing that tag, to avoid you getting bombed by the bash police ;-) ELSE get/install cygwin or mingw for your PC and then you can do bash/shell scripting. Good luck.

Comment: shelter, thanks for the heads-up, as for powerShell i was just wondering if it was possible to do this with cmd.exe

Comment: Probably, but why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set ORIGINALFILE=q34614930.txt
set MODIFIEDFILE=u:\temp1.txt
set MODIFIEDFILE2=u:\temp_backup.txt
set SEARCHVALUE=0
set REPLACEVALUE=1
::for demo purpose make cop of original file as original will be overwritten
copy %ORIGINALFILE% %MODIFIEDFILE2% >NUL 2>nul
REM echo "all set"
REM timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

::everything is set now change the 6th item on the line 5 to a "1"
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r ".*" "%ORIGINALFILE%"') do (
 IF "%%a"=="5" (
  FOR /f "tokens=1-6*delims=," %%A IN ("%%b") DO echo(%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%replacevalue%,%%G
 ) ELSE ECHO(%%b
)
)>"%MODIFIEDFILE%"
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q34614930.txt` containing some test data for my testing. I also changed the filenames to suit mys system.

In the absence of representative data, I use the following and replaced column 6 in line 5.

> line 1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
>   line 2,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
>   
>   line 4,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
>   line 5,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
>   line 6,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8

Result

> line 1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
>   line 2,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
>   
>   line 4,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
>   line 5,col2,col3,col4,col5,1,col7,col8
>   line 6,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8

Without representative data, we're guessing.

Comment: @Fernand : Don't forget to 'accept' the answer that helps you solve your problem. Click on the Green Chk Mark outside of the top left of the answer that helps you. Once you have 16 rep points, you can up-vote answers as well. Good luck.

Comment: Due to circumstances i wont be able to test it until tomorrow, but as far as i can determine this will work for me :) thanks @Magoo,

Comment: and @shelter, i will do a soon as i get to test the code, thanks guys

Comment: @Magoo, thanks for the help this worked for me, just needed to modify the `) ELSE ECHO(%%b`   into   `) ELSE ECHO.%%b`  in order to copy blank lines as wel, but for the rest much obliged :)